# PHP - Get the middle number

Tags: php, string, substr

So basically i am using `file_get_contents()` function to get the contents of a page. I put those contents in the variable `$content` so i can work with it.`<p>` On this page the following info is displayed **Server (1.7.2) playercount: 400/500**

I have to get two pieces of info, the player count on its own (400/500), and the server version (1.7.2). I managed to get the player count with the following code:

```
$playercount = substr($content, strpos($content, ")") + 1);
```

that returns `":400/500"`

Now here is my problem when i try do the same thing for the server version (1.7.2) I get no return, i presume it is because it doesn't count it as a string:

```
$version = substr($content, -16, -11);
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Is that info the only text displayed? Or is it something surrounded by plenty of other texts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex match for both informations:

```
preg_match('/^\w+\s\((\d\.\d\.\d)\)\s\w+:\s(\d+\/\d+)$/', $content, $result);
print_r($result);
```

See fiddle http://ideone.com/4vAgdE

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression as rabudde suggested. Or, you can get the string between `Server (` and `)` to find the server version.

Answer (score 0):

I did this

```
preg_match("/^.*?([0-9\.]+).*?([0-9\/]+)/i",$content,$matches);
$playercount=$matches[1];
$version=$matches[2];
```